# how to print jTextfield value with formatting?

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, printing, formatting, jtextfield

I'm a very beginner at java, so please forgive my lack of knowledge.
 I want to create a simple invoice for my test app. to do that I want to get a jTextfield value and print it as a bill.

```
        MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("header massege");
        MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("footer massage");
        ;


        try{


        jTextfield.print(header, footer);

        }  catch(java.awt.print.PrinterException e) {

            {

                    System.err.format("Cannot print %s%n", e.getMessage());

                    }

}
```

how can I add "your total is $" in front of jTextfield output ?

example:-

this is current format:

---header---

jTextfield output (price)

---footer---

---

**I want to accomplish this**:

---header---

your total is $ = 100 (jTextfield output)

---footer---

---

how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't do much printing, but how about this:

```
MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("header massege");
MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("footer massage");
try {
    JTextField fieldForPrint = new JTextField("your total is $ " + jTextField1.getText());
    fieldForPrint.print(header, footer);
} catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e) {
    System.err.format("Cannot print %s%n", e.getMessage());
}
```